# Restart need to setup wifi access point in Win7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My coleague has set up my notebook that it can serve as wifi access point for mobile phones. I start it with following script:

```
START cmd.exe /k "C:\Windows\System32\netsh wlan start hostednetwork"
```

It works fine until laptop goes to sleep mode. Then I am unable to start this access point. I found the only workaround - restart windows which is really annoying. Other colleagues do not experience this issue. How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: I would try to stop the hostednetwork with `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork` and then start anew.

Comment: This step did not work for me. I just tried hw button to switch wireless networking off and then on and it seems to help. I need to perform verification yet.

Comment: Your laptop shouldn't go into sleep mode. You could configure the time via command line too, i.e. `powercfg -x -standby-timeout-dc 240` (sleep mode after four hours).

Comment: Let me describe it more deeply. I setup AP and it is working fine. Then I let laptop sleep because I go home. Next day I want to continue but supplied start/stop scripts have no effect. I had to restart windows.

Comment: It seems your wlan adapter doesn't function properly after sleep mode. Is that so? You could test, if disabling/enabling via network connections will be successful. It it is you could add two lines to your script, that will do this disabling/enabling too, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021466/disabling-ethernet-connection-with-command-line